# Where Clause in update

Tags: sql

Can we use where clause in update by fetching values from other table in where clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-to-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to do. Show us your query attempt!

Answer (score 0):

Several options, provide more info by editing your question for better responses...

```
update MyTable
set MyColumn = 'Chicken Nuggets'
where SomeColumn in (select SomethingElse from AnotherTable)
```

Or an exists (a better choice):

```
update MyTable
set MyColumn = 'Chicken Nuggets'
where exists (select 1 from SomeOtherTable where SomethingElse = SomeColumn)
```